# How to nest 3 arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays

I need to nest 3 `arrays` (so the first `array` contains an `array`, which also contains an `array`). Im having success with 2 `arrays` but I can't get 3 to work.

I had my code working with 2 `arrays` (which worked jusr fine) but I can't get 3 `arrays` to be nested.

My current code:

```
if (!empty($sections)) {
    foreach ($sections as $d) {
        $row_array = array();
        $row_array["id"] = intval($d["id"]);
        $row_array["sname"] = $d["sname"];
        $row_array["sicon"] = $d["sicon"];
        $row_array["perc"] = intval($d["perc"]);
        $row_array["pvalue"] = intval($d["pvalue"]);
        $row_array["vfixed"] = intval($d["vfixed"]);
        $row_array["sectionValues"] = array();
        array_push($row_array["sectionValues"],
            intval($d["perc"]),
            intval($d["id"]),
            0
        );
        $row_array["sectionIndicators"] = array();
        //loop indicators
        if (!empty($indicators)) {
            foreach ($indicators as $v) {
                if ($d["id"] == $v["idsec"]) {
                    /*$row_array["sectionIndicators"][] = array(
                        "iid" => intval($v["iid"]),
                        "iname" => $v["iname"],
                        "perc" => intval($v["perc"]),
                        "pvalue" => intval($v["pvalue"]),
                        "vfixed" => intval($v["vfixed"])
                    );*/
                    $row_array["sectionIndicators"]["iid"] = intval($v["iid"]);
                    $row_array["sectionIndicators"]["iname"] = $v["iname"];
                    $row_array["sectionIndicators"]["perc"] = intval($v["perc"]);
                    $row_array["sectionIndicators"]["pvalue"] = intval($v["pvalue"]);
                    $row_array["sectionIndicators"]["vfixed"] = intval($v["vfixed"]);
                    $row_array["sectionIndicators"]["finalArray"] = array();
                }
            }
        }
        array_push($data, $row_array);
    }
}
```

The part that I commented out is my working part (with 2 arrays).The new part works but only contains the last row of `$indicators` so it seems like the loop isn't working this way.

The `$row_array["sectionIndicators"]["finalArray"] = array();` will contain the last nested `array`.

Any help is much appreciated.

**SOLUTION**

I found out that I had to give an index. My solution:

```
if (!empty($sections)) {
    foreach ($sections as $d) {
        $row_array = array();
        $row_array["id"] = intval($d["id"]);
        $row_array["sname"] = $d["sname"];
        $row_array["sicon"] = $d["sicon"];
        $row_array["perc"] = intval($d["perc"]);
        $row_array["pvalue"] = intval($d["pvalue"]);
        $row_array["vfixed"] = intval($d["vfixed"]);
        $row_array["sectionValues"] = array();
        array_push($row_array["sectionValues"],
            intval($d["perc"]),
            intval($d["id"]),
            0
        );
        $row_array["sectionIndicators"] = array();
        //loop indicators
        if (!empty($indicators)) {
            $i=-1;
            foreach ($indicators as $v) {
                if ($d["id"] == $v["idsec"]) {
                    $i++;
                    $row_array["sectionIndicators"][$i]["iid"] = intval($v["iid"]);
                    $row_array["sectionIndicators"][$i]["iname"] = $v["iname"];
                    $row_array["sectionIndicators"][$i]["perc"] = intval($v["perc"]);
                    $row_array["sectionIndicators"][$i]["pvalue"] = intval($v["pvalue"]);
                    $row_array["sectionIndicators"][$i]["vfixed"] = intval($v["vfixed"]);
                    $row_array["sectionIndicators"][$i]["finalArray"] = array();
                    array_push($row_array["sectionIndicators"][$i]["finalArray"],
                        intval($v["perc"]),
                        intval($d["id"]),
                        intval($v["iid"])
                    );
                }
            }
        }
        array_push($data, $row_array);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are overwriting `$row_array["sectionIndicators"]` with a new empty array in each iteration of that inner foreach loop. // What structure you actually _want_ here, is rather unclear.

Comment: That's my mistake. when I set the `$row_array["sectionIndicators"]` in the first loop, it still doesn't work though (will update my question).

Comment: I can't see where `$indicators` gets set, and that seems to be an important part of the problem.

Comment: Hi @BenHillier. True, my code isn't complete (to save lines) but `$indicators` is set. I already found my solution. wil edit my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I had to give an index. My solution:

```
if (!empty($sections)) {
    foreach ($sections as $d) {
        $row_array = array();
        $row_array["id"] = intval($d["id"]);
        $row_array["sname"] = $d["sname"];
        $row_array["sicon"] = $d["sicon"];
        $row_array["perc"] = intval($d["perc"]);
        $row_array["pvalue"] = intval($d["pvalue"]);
        $row_array["vfixed"] = intval($d["vfixed"]);
        $row_array["sectionValues"] = array();
        array_push($row_array["sectionValues"],
            intval($d["perc"]),
            intval($d["id"]),
            0
        );
        $row_array["sectionIndicators"] = array();
        //loop indicators
        if (!empty($indicators)) {
            $i=-1;
            foreach ($indicators as $v) {
                if ($d["id"] == $v["idsec"]) {
                    $i++;
                    $row_array["sectionIndicators"][$i]["iid"] = intval($v["iid"]);
                    $row_array["sectionIndicators"][$i]["iname"] = $v["iname"];
                    $row_array["sectionIndicators"][$i]["perc"] = intval($v["perc"]);
                    $row_array["sectionIndicators"][$i]["pvalue"] = intval($v["pvalue"]);
                    $row_array["sectionIndicators"][$i]["vfixed"] = intval($v["vfixed"]);
                    $row_array["sectionIndicators"][$i]["finalArray"] = array();
                    array_push($row_array["sectionIndicators"][$i]["finalArray"],
                        intval($v["perc"]),
                        intval($d["id"]),
                        intval($v["iid"])
                    );
                }
            }
        }
        array_push($data, $row_array);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

// Assumption that your array is like this :
$sections = [0 => ['id'=>1, 'sname'=>'Sname', 'sicon'=>'SIcon', 'perc'=>'Perc', 'pvalue'=>'Pvalue', 'vfixed'=>'Vfixed'], 1 => ['id'=>2, 'sname'=>'Sname2', 'sicon'=>'SIcon2', 'perc'=>'Perc2', 'pvalue'=>'Pvalue2', 'vfixed'=>'Vfixed2']];
$indicators = [ 0 => ['idsec'=>1, 'iid'=>1, 'iname'=>'viname', 'perc'=>'vperc', 'pvalue'=>'vpvalue', 'vfixed'=>'vVfixed'], 1 => ['idsec'=>2, 'iid'=>2, 'iname'=>'viname2', 'perc'=>'vperc2', 'pvalue'=>'vpvalue2', 'vfixed'=>'vVfixed2']];

// Initialisation your result array
$data = [];

if (!empty($sections)) {
    foreach ($sections as $d) {
        $row_array = array();
        $row_array["id"] = intval($d["id"]);
        $row_array["sname"] = $d["sname"];
        $row_array["sicon"] = $d["sicon"];
        $row_array["perc"] = intval($d["perc"]);
        $row_array["pvalue"] = intval($d["pvalue"]);
        $row_array["vfixed"] = intval($d["vfixed"]);
        $row_array["sectionValues"] = array();
        array_push($row_array["sectionValues"],
            intval($d["perc"]),
            intval($d["id"]),
            0
        );
        //loop indicators
        if (!empty($indicators)) {
            foreach ($indicators as $v) {
                if ($d['id'] == $v['idsec']) {
                    $row_array["sectionIndicators"] = array();
                    $row_array["sectionIndicators"][] = array(
                        "iid" => intval($v["iid"]),
                        "iname" => $v["iname"],
                        "perc" => intval($v["perc"]),
                        "pvalue" => intval($v["pvalue"]),
                        "vfixed" => intval($v["vfixed"])
                    );
                    $row_array["sectionIndicators"]["iid"] = intval($v["iid"]);
                    $row_array["sectionIndicators"]["iname"] = $v["iname"];
                    $row_array["sectionIndicators"]["perc"] = intval($v["perc"]);
                    $row_array["sectionIndicators"]["pvalue"] = intval($v["pvalue"]);
                    $row_array["sectionIndicators"]["vfixed"] = intval($v["vfixed"]);
                    $row_array["sectionIndicators"]["finalArray"] = array();
                }
            }
        }
        array_push($data, $row_array);
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r( $data );
```

Result :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [sname] => Sname
            [sicon] => SIcon
            [perc] => 0
            [pvalue] => 0
            [vfixed] => 0
            [sectionValues] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 1
                    [2] => 0
                )

            [sectionIndicators] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [iid] => 1
                            [iname] => viname
                            [perc] => 0
                            [pvalue] => 0
                            [vfixed] => 0
                        )

                    [iid] => 1
                    [iname] => viname
                    [perc] => 0
                    [pvalue] => 0
                    [vfixed] => 0
                    [finalArray] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [sname] => Sname2
            [sicon] => SIcon2
            [perc] => 0
            [pvalue] => 0
            [vfixed] => 0
            [sectionValues] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 2
                    [2] => 0
                )

            [sectionIndicators] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [iid] => 2
                            [iname] => viname2
                            [perc] => 0
                            [pvalue] => 0
                            [vfixed] => 0
                        )

                    [iid] => 2
                    [iname] => viname2
                    [perc] => 0
                    [pvalue] => 0
                    [vfixed] => 0
                    [finalArray] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Tnx for your help. See my solution in my question.